# had just/had hardly...when

Tags: grammar

I have two groups of sentences. In each group, do the two sentences have the same meaning? Is the first sentence in each group less common?

1A. Hardly had I arrived when it started to rain.

1B. I had just arrived when it started to rain.

2A. Hardly had I reached the station when the train came.

2B. I had just reached the station when the train came.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I see very little difference in these constructions. Perhaps the “Hardly ...”. versions place a little more emphasis on the writer (or speaker) than on the rain or train but that is probably my personal reaction; others may disagree.

Comment: In daily speech, which version is more common, the "hardly..." version or the "just.." version? Thanks.

Comment: I hear the just version much more than the hardly version.